# Creating user buttons to change task list view

Tags: sharepoint-online, task-list, sub-site, button, customization

On a sub-site I would like to add buttons above a task list so that the user can manipulate the view. For example a checkbox which when ticked includes completed tasks, or a button to change the date range of tasks displayed.

I imagine I would have to create a view for each case, and the button then calls this view and passes parameters to it.

From my research I can't find anywhere how to add buttons (I assumed there would be something like the ActiveX controls in Excel). Furthermore I guess I would use a workflow to change the views and pass parameters but I have also seen mention of JSOM to customise pages in this way.

I am a SP newbie and any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Content Editor or Script Editor web part on your site, put Html and JSOM (JavaScript Object Model) code and that's it. You can perform any action supported by JSOM APIs.

For more details, please refer to:

- https://www.codesharepoint.com/rest-api/create-view-in-sharepoint-using-rest-api

And each view has its special server relative URL, we just need to perform the navigation action to the corresponding view in the OnClick function.

BR